# can I use jsp or servlet page in android application

Tags: android

can I use jsp or servlet page in android application

Comment: JSP/Servlets is a server side technology. You can `access` the JSP/Servlet from an Android device, but as I know cannot implement their functionality on an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.  For instance [this article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Jetty-Servlet-Ported-to-Google-Android-81049.shtml) talks about a port of Jetty to Android, and Jetty supports Servlets and JSPs.

Whether it is a good idea to run a web server on your mobile phone is another question entirely ...

Comment: iJetty doesn't support JSP compiling from scratch. Either you have to implement the compile process on your own or you have to precompile and dexify the JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSP, servlets or deploy entire web application war packaged on Android device. Check http://tjws.sf.net it is an application server for Android platform and works perfectly from my needs.

Comment: Here's the same: Either you have to implement the compile process on your own or you have to precompile and dexify the JSPs. But in contrast to iJetty here I found the hint to use 7bee script to do that [7bee 1.1.1](http://knitknot.info/download/7bee/bee-1.1.1.zip)